# error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of Unit - Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to save the results into a text file using:

```
results.collect().foreach { rule => println("[" + rule.antecedent.mkString(",") + "=>" + rule.consequent.mkString(",") + "]," + rule.confidence)}.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/rules")
```

But I got this error:

```
<console>:43: error: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of Unit
              results.collect().foreach { rule => println("[" + rule.antecedent.mkString(",") + "=>" + rule.consequent.mkString(",") + "]," + rule.confidence)}.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/rules")
```

What I need to change? I don't understand the error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save use:

```
results.map { rule => 
     "[" + rule.antecedent.mkString(",") + "=>" + rule.consequent.mkString(",") + "]," + rule.confidence
}.saveAsTextFile("/user/cloudera/rules")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `foreach` operation returns a `Unit`, which is a stand-in for an empty return value:

```
scala> val a = (0 to 5).foreach(println)
0
1
2
3
4
5
a: Unit = ()
```

If you want to save your original `results` you will need to use something like:

```
results.collect.saveAsTextFile(...)
```

Otherwise if you are trying to apply an operation to each element of `results.collect` and then save the result, then you will need to use a `map` and do something else to each element (because `print` also returns a `Unit`).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message when I had initialized the variable with `spark.read` instead of `sc`. One of them returns a `DataSet` that doesn't have the `saveAsTextFile` method, the other one returns an RDD that does. Hope it helps someone.